# javascript typeof doesn't work with PHP variables?

Tags: php, javascript, variables

Just wondering, does "typeof" javascript verification (you know, what you do to check for undefined variables in javascript) not work the same way with PHP vars?

I do

```
alert(typeof <? echo $_SESSION['thing'] ?>);
```

and this doesn't even execute (I'd figure it would at least pop up as blank)

But if I do

```
alert(<? echo $_SESSION['thing'] ?>);
```

the alert says "undefined"

So I'm wondering if the correct way to check for undefined PHP vars using javascript is just to echo them? If it's not please correct me, but if it is I thought it'd be good to share.

Thanks

Comment: just echo them. i do it all the time since its a php variable not a js one.

Comment: I guess that heavily depends on the value of your `$_SESSION['thing']`. What values do you expect to be there?

Comment: php is server side, javascript is client side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as PHP variables in JavaScript.

What PHP is doing is "composing" the output text of the JavaScript.

Hit "View source" and look at the final text that PHP put together.

Adding to the answer @Chief17 gave you:

```
var x_string_val = "<?php echo ((isset($value) AND !empty($value)) ? $value : $default) ?>";
var x_any = <?php echo ((isset($value) AND !empty($value)) ? $value : $default) ?>;
var x_type = typeof(<?php echo ((isset($value) AND !empty($value)) ? $value : $default) ?>);
```

Be sure to either output quotes from PHP or quote the value in javascript if it's a string. Otherwise it will likely cause more errors.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is read a result from a PHP variable into a ternary condition to set a variable in javascript. If the PHP is empty/undefined, set variable to 0, if not, set it to whatevers inside

Comment: Whoa that is a lot to verify one variable isn't it? I still don't under why this will not work...<?echo $_SESSION['thing']; ?> == "undefined") ? alert("yes") : alert("no");

Comment: If thing was 4, wouldn't javascript read that as 4 == "undefined" (False, so popup "No")?

Comment: And if thing were undefined the PHP would write it as "undefined" == "undefined", wouldn't it?

Comment: In order to achive the undefined result you should have PHP output the name of a variable that is undefined (doesn't exist) in JavaScript. When I say name I mean unquoted **inexistent_variable** as opposed to **"inexistent_variable"** which would be interpreted as a string of value "inexistent_variable".

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['thing'])) {
   echo 'thing is set';
} else {
   echo 'thing is not set';
}
```

This is the PHP way to check if a variable has been set.

http://uk.php.net/isset

***Edit:***

I guess I would do this if I wanted to check a PHP variable in JavaScript:

```
<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.(isset($variable) ? $variable : 'Undefined Variable').'");</script>';
?>
```

The above code checks if the variable is set in PHP, if it is, it `echo`s it out into the alert statement, if it isn't, a blank value is alerted instead.

Comment: The code would work, depending on your goal, but your answer doesn't address the actual problem of OP misunderstanding what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Just think what would be happening. PHP is executed on the server. The `result` of the PHP statement is inserted in the HTML/JavaScript that is sent to the client.

So if your session variable contains `Foo`, the result would be

```
alert(typeof Foo);
```

and

```
alert(Foo);
```

As you may understand, Foo is not defined in the context of your client side JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

You need to assign the variable to a javascript variable. If you look at the HTML source after your php has rendered you'll probably see something like:

```
alert(typeof some value for thing);
```

which would be a syntax error.

Do this instead

```
var thing = "<?php echo $_SESSION['thing']; ?>";
alert( typeof thing );
```

Comment: And then the statement `var thing = some value for thing;` would fail instead.

Comment: @GolezTrol indeed I missed the quotes around the PHP. Fixed now.

Answer (score -2):

```
alert(typeof <? echo $_SESSION['thing'] ?>);
```

This has a bad syntax - it should be `alert(typeof(some_variable))`

```
alert(<? echo $_SESSION['thing'] ?>);
```

This should be like

```
alert("<?php echo $_SESSION['thing']; ?>");
```

And what you are trying to do makes no sense because how is js supposed to use variables from different language? o.O

Comment: typeof is an operator not a function, it's not bad syntax it is correct and allowed to use it without the parenthesis. It is however bad practice and you should use the parenthesis.

Comment: Bad practise to not use parentheses with an operator? Do you write (1)+(2) as well?

Comment: Quoting whatever PHP outputs in strings means that the end result would always be a string. But if you want to output **10e19** from PHP, javascript will recognise that as perfectly valid numerical syntax even without the quotes. With the qootes you could never output a javascript array **[]** or a javascript object **{}**

Comment: @GolezTrol Point taken troll, you know I meant bad practice with relation to a unary right hand sided operator that might otherwise get mixed up in other operations, for example **typeof(false)** versus **typeof false * 34** (if the * is an accidental leftover from editing stuff while debuging.

Comment: And what is the difference, `typeof(false) * 34` probably means the same as `typeof false * 34`. Just making it look like a function doesn't mean the JS engine will treat it as such.

Comment: Well because of operator precedence and bracketing **typeof(false * 34)** yields a result of type **string** with a value of **"number"** while **typeof false * 34** yields the value **NaN**.

Comment: Indeed **typeof(false) * 34** yields the same as **typeof false * 34** but the point is that bracketing and operation precedents go together and it is good practice not for the sake of making it look like a function.